# Creating a Different Filter for One Column

Tags: sql

I have this select query on two tables, I am pulling the data for everything with a warehouse code = 002 from IM_WH, however I have one field QuantityOnPurchaseOrder (IM_WH.PO) that I want to pull the data for warehouse code 009, just in that one column all other columns to stay with 002 as the filter.

```
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.IM_WH.IC, dbo.IM_WH.OnHand, dbo.IM_WH.SO, dbo.IM_WH.PO, 
                     dbo.IM_WH.RP, dbo.IM_WH.MIN, dbo.IM_WH.PHYD
    FROM            dbo.IM_WH INNER JOIN
                     dbo.CI_Item ON dbo.IM_WH.IC = dbo.CI_Item.IC
    WHERE        (dbo.IM_WH.WarehouseCode = '002') AND (dbo.IM_WH.RP = 'R') AND (dbo.IM_WH.IC LIKE 'WPF%')
    ORDER BY dbo.IM_WH.IC
```

I attempted to use a CASE statement but I don't think that was correct, since I need to output an actual field.  In the screenshot I sow the different records for IM_WH.IC = WPF01-CC102-FROST,the qtyonpo is 0 in all rows except the row with warehouse code =009 so I want the 1000 to be in the output.

Data

| ItemCode | OnHand | QTYPO | WarehouseCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WPF01-CC102-FROST | 10 | 0 | 002 |
| WPF01-CC102-FROST | 0 | 1000 | 009 |
| WPF01-CC102-GREEN | 9 | 0 | 002 |

Output

| ItemCode | OnHand | QTYPO | WarehouseCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WPF01-CC102-FROST | 10 | 1000 | 002 |
| WPF01-CC102-GREEN | 9 | 0 | 002 |

Comment: Please provide both sample input data and expected outcome as table with text rather than uploading screenshots.

Comment: I'd do a GROUP BY here.

Comment: @jarlh is it just grouping by the warehouse? The response from Zack looks good but as beginner as I am, I got lost with it, probably my fault because i left off information.   Can't seem to translate it to my original data and also trying to create this in the Design View in SQL, which I know is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

So all you need is a self join. Keep your current query (pulling records with a warehouse code of 002), and add a LEFT JOIN for 009 records.

Since it seems that, based on your example `WPF01-CC102-GREEN` record, you want to keep the 002 QTYPO if there's no 009 record, you can use a `COALESCE`.

A couple of additional notes:

- I'm not sure why you have a `TOP (100) PERCENT`, since that would just return all records. You should be able to just get rid of that.
- Once you specify the schema (`dbo`) in the `FROM` clause, you don't need to keep repeating it elsewhere.

Anyways, something like this should work:

```sql
SELECT
    WH002.IC AS ItemCode,
    WH002.OnHand,
    COALESCE(WH009.QTYPO, WH002.QTYPO) AS QTYPO,
    WH002.WarehouseCode
FROM #IM_WH WH002
    LEFT JOIN #IM_WH WH009 ON
        WH009.IC = WH002.IC
        AND WH009.WarehouseCode = '009'
WHERE 
    wh002.WarehouseCode = '002'
    AND wh002.RP = 'R'
    AND wh002.IC LIKE 'WPF%'
```

(working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xs8BYT4W)).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting some inside help and they provided me with this code to solve my problem, I went another route and used a formula in excel and added a column to use a workaround instead of SQL.  Never used table expressions before so nice to have an example to go off of now.

```
WITH wh2data AS (SELECT dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnHand, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnSalesOrder, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnPurchaseOrder,dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ReorderPointQty, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.MinimumOrderQty, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.LastPhysicalCountDate
FROM            dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse INNER JOIN
                     dbo.CI_Item ON dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode = dbo.CI_Item.ItemCode
WHERE        (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.WarehouseCode = '002') AND (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ReorderMethod = 'R') AND (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode LIKE 'WPF%')),

wh9data AS (SELECT dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode, dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.QuantityOnPurchaseOrder
FROM            dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse INNER JOIN
                     dbo.CI_Item ON dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode = dbo.CI_Item.ItemCode
WHERE        (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.WarehouseCode = '009') AND (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ReorderMethod = 'R') AND (dbo.IM_ItemWarehouse.ItemCode LIKE 'WPF%'))

SELECT wh2data.ItemCode, wh2data.QuantityOnHand, wh2data.QuantityOnSalesOrder, wh2data.QuantityOnPurchaseOrder,
wh2data.ReorderPointQty, wh2data.MinimumOrderQty, wh2data.LastPhysicalCountDate, wh9data.QuantityOnPurchaseOrder AS QtyOnPurchaseOrderWh9
FROM wh2data FULL OUTER JOIN wh9data ON wh2data.ItemCode = wh9data.ItemCode;
```